# Run both HTTP and HTTPS in same program

Tags: http, https, go

Why can't I run both HTTP and HTTPS from the same golang program?

Here is the code where the two servers are initiated.. The server which is initiated first will run - the second won't.. If they are switched arround the other will run and the other won't..

No errors are returned when running the program, but the requests `http://www.localhost` or `https://secure.localhost` times out

```
//  Start HTTP
err_http := http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), http_r)
if err_http != nil {
    log.Fatal("Web server (HTTP): ", err_http)
}

//  Start HTTPS
err_https := http.ListenAndServeTLS(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", ssl_port), "D:/Go/src/www/ssl/public.crt", "D:/Go/src/www/ssl/private.key", https_r)
if err_https != nil {
    log.Fatal("Web server (HTTPS): ", err_https)
}
```

Here is the complete code

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "io"
    "runtime"

    // go get github.com/gorilla/mux
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

const (
    HOST = "localhost"
)

func Handler_404(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Oops, something went wrong!")
}

func Handler_www(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello world :)")
}

func Handler_api(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Fprint(w, "This is the API")
}

func Handler_secure(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Fprint(w, "This is Secure")
}

func redirect(r *mux.Router, from string, to string){
    r.Host(from).Subrouter().HandleFunc("/", func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        http.Redirect(w, r, to, 301)
    })
}

func main(){
    port := 9000
    ssl_port := 443

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

    http_r := mux.NewRouter()
    https_r := mux.NewRouter()

    //  HTTP 404
    http_r.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(Handler_404)

    //  Redirect "http://HOST" => "http://www.HOST"
    redirect(http_r, HOST, fmt.Sprintf("http://www.%s:%d", HOST, port))

    //  Redirect "http://secure.HOST" => "https://secure.HOST"
    redirect(http_r, "secure."+HOST, fmt.Sprintf("https://secure.%s", HOST))

    www := http_r.Host("www."+HOST).Subrouter()
    www.HandleFunc("/", Handler_www)

    api := http_r.Host("api."+HOST).Subrouter()
    api.HandleFunc("/", Handler_api)

    secure := https_r.Host("secure."+HOST).Subrouter()
    secure.HandleFunc("/", Handler_secure)

    //  Start HTTP
    err_http := http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), http_r)
    if err_http != nil {
        log.Fatal("Web server (HTTP): ", err_http)
    }

    //  Start HTTPS
    err_https := http.ListenAndServeTLS(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", ssl_port), "D:/Go/src/www/ssl/public.crt", "D:/Go/src/www/ssl/private.key", https_r)
    if err_https != nil {
        log.Fatal("Web server (HTTPS): ", err_https)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[ListenAndServe](http://godoc.org/net/http#ListenAndServe) and [ListenAndServeTLS](http://godoc.org/net/http#ListenAndServeTLS) open the listening socket and then loop forever serving client connections. These functions only return on an error.

The main goroutine never gets to the starting the TLS server because the main goroutine is busy waiting for HTTP connections in ListenAndServe.

To fix the problem, start the HTTP server in a new goroutine:

```
//  Start HTTP
go func() {
    err_http := http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), http_r)
    if err_http != nil {
        log.Fatal("Web server (HTTP): ", err_http)
    }
 }()

//  Start HTTPS
err_https := http.ListenAndServeTLS(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", ssl_port),     "D:/Go/src/www/ssl/public.crt", "D:/Go/src/www/ssl/private.key", https_r)
if err_https != nil {
    log.Fatal("Web server (HTTPS): ", err_https)
}
```

Answer (score 12):

As previously said, both [ListenAndServe](http://godoc.org/net/http#ListenAndServe) and [ListenAndServeTLS](http://godoc.org/net/http#ListenAndServeTLS) are blocking. That being said, I would agree that examples above are in fact resolving your issue as the point is to be in goroutine BUT same examples are not quite following go idioms.

You should be using error channels here as you want to capture ALL errors that are sent to you instead of having just one error returned back. Here's fully working sample that starts HTTP as HTTPS servers and return errors as channel that's later on used just to display errors.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func Run(addr string, sslAddr string, ssl map[string]string) chan error {

    errs := make(chan error)

    // Starting HTTP server
    go func() {
        log.Printf("Staring HTTP service on %s ...", addr)

        if err := http.ListenAndServe(addr, nil); err != nil {
            errs <- err
        }

    }()

    // Starting HTTPS server
    go func() {
        log.Printf("Staring HTTPS service on %s ...", addr)
        if err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(sslAddr, ssl["cert"], ssl["key"], nil); err != nil {
            errs <- err
        }
    }()

    return errs
}

func sampleHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte("This is an example server.\n"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", sampleHandler)

    errs := Run(":8080", ":10443", map[string]string{
        "cert": "/path/to/cert.pem",
        "key":  "/path/to/key.pem",
    })

    // This will run forever until channel receives error
    select {
    case err := <-errs:
        log.Printf("Could not start serving service due to (error: %s)", err)
    }

}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Except that almost always the *only* thing done with a ListenAndServer error is log it and exiting (allowing an external mechanism to restart the whole server/process if desired). E.g. exactly what the question and answers had with `log.Fatal()` bailing on the first encountered error. If that's the desired behavior then anything more than what they were doing is distracting overkill.

Comment: That's true Dave. I usually over complicate thing. I always have at the code level restart logic rather than things like supervisord. That's something I use if entire process goes down. If however one goes down and second one stays up than entire script will be bugged. Must admit that I did not experience that with http that much but did experience a lot with AMQP where one stays up, second one goes down and make entire logic bugged so I need to restart under internal loop. Than i took that approach and using it everywhere where I have more than 1 listener lol

Comment: @NevioVesić 's example has merits with consistency. The only thing I'd add would be a channel to shutdown the go routine that didn't error, especially if one were to wish to start it up again after handling the error.

Comment: with one clause - the select block is redundant. A simple `err := <-errs` would suffice.

Answer (score 5):

```
func serveHTTP(mux *http.ServeMux, errs chan<- error) {
  errs <- http.ListenAndServe(":80", mux)
}

func serveHTTPS(mux *http.ServeMux, errs chan<- error) {
  errs <- http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "fullchain.pem", "privkey.pem", mux)
}


func main() {
  mux := http.NewServeMux()
  // setup routes for mux     // define your endpoints
  errs := make(chan error, 1) // a channel for errors
  go serveHTTP(mux, errs)     // start the http server in a thread
  go serveHTTPS(mux, errs)    // start the https server in a thread
  log.Fatal(<-errs)           // block until one of the servers writes an error
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `ListenAndServe` (and `ListenAndServeTLS`) functions do not return to their caller (unless an error is encountered). You can test this by trying to print something in between the two calls.