# creating multiple http Server instances in Go does not work

Tags: go

I am trying to create 2 HTTP server in my go lang app and this is how I try to achieve it :

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    server := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":9000",
        //Handler:  http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    }
    server.ListenAndServe()


    server2 := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8000",
        //Handler:  http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    }
    server2.ListenAndServe()

}
```

The issue I am having is when I go to the browser to make a request to `http://localhost:9000/` it goes, but when I make a request to `http://localhost:8000/` I get "Site cannot be reached". Why can't I create to instances of an HTTP server in Go?

Comment: `http.Server.ListenAndServe` blocks the Go routine while it is accepting connections.

Comment: @TimCooper so is it possible to create to instances?

Comment: Yes, by using goroutines you can run multiple server instances.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090301/run-both-http-and-https-in-same-program/29468115

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749579/can-i-setup-multi-port-from-one-web-app-with-go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like [Tim Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142162/tim-cooper) was saying `ListenAndServe` is blocking so the first server starts up, but then does not proceed to the second call. An easy way to fix this would be to start `server` in a goroutine of its own like

```
func main() {

    server := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":9000",
        //Handler:  http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    }
    go server.ListenAndServe()


    server2 := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8000",
        //Handler:  http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    }
    server2.ListenAndServe()

}
```